# zfs for Linux – formatting disks

Tags: linux, raid, zfs

I just installed the zfs file system for Linux, but now I do not know how to format a drive with it. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop and trying to format two external hard disks to mirror each other. Is there a command to mirror each disk or is RAID a better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to the `zpool` and `zfs` man pages.

eg:

```
zpool create mypool <disk or partition>

zpool create mypool1 mirror <disk1> <disk2>
```

Comment: @ultrapenguin Please clarify what you wanted to tell with a comment instead of an edit. In any case, a storage pool is the foundation of ZFS, not something you might avoid with gparted or whatever.

Comment: [Clarification] If I just formatted a standalone drive with ZFS would I see a performance improvement or anything?

Comment: Disks are already formatted when you buy them, all of them and since decades. You cannot "format" a disk with ZFS otherwise you use a tool that misuse this term for another. You can create a pool on a whole disk, on a partition, a slice, a file and a combination of these. The best performance is expected with whole disks, the worst with file based pools.